# is it possible for Firefox to ignore http 302 permanently moved and still do the redirect next time you visit (like a temporary moved)?

Tags: firefox

We have a bug in a library which is used in a ton of web applications. The bug is that it redirects the user to a login page using 302 permanently moved instead of temporary moved. This causes Firefox 5 (and possibly later) to cache the response and redirect the user everytime he tries to access the page.

I have looked into about:config properties, but cannot find anything worth tuning.

I've looked into the property: network.http.redirection-limit;20 , but I dont think this is the correct value to change.

Comment: I once had a bug like this in an HTTP server.  I took the route of _fixing the bug_, and kicking myself for such a mistake, rather than _breaking the protocol_.  Breaking protocol to accommodate bugs is a cause of problems, not a solution for them.  Gresham's Law trumps Postel's Principle.

Comment: You need to fix the library instead of trying to break standardized behaviour in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not apply to me anymore. We had to take the pain and fix the library. All in all this was the healthiest solution!